# React componentWillUnmount not being called upon page navigation

Tags: reactjs

I have a component:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("HERE")
    }

    render() {<div>Hello world</div>}
}
```

When I do anything that navigates me away from the page (e.g. click on a hyperlink, back button click, etc.), the `console.log` statement is not printed. Can anybody help me out?

Neither the top level parent component nor any of the `componentWillUnmount` of its child components are called.

A lot of the existing questions around this is referring to React native issues. I am using React 16, not React Native. I have no problems with page navigation otherwise. I need to call a specific third-party function when my component unmounts and the lifecycle method isn't even being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about regular browser page navigation (as opposed to [react router](https://reactrouter.com) type navigation), when you navigate away from the page the component does not unmount in the React lifecycle sense. It's still mounted when the entire page gets destroyed.

If you need to do something before navigating away from your app's page entirely you could try listening for a [pagehide event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event), but be aware:

> Like the unload and beforeunload events, this event is not reliably fired by browsers, especially on mobile.